# Contact form with PHP in static website

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

i've finally finish my website, the only thing left is the contact form.
It's a static website and i'm wondering if there is any solution for a functional contact form.
I've tried with Formspree, it works great but i want if possible, a way to send an email directly from my website without using a third party service.
Here's the html form

```
<form role="form" class="contact-form" method="post" action="php/contact.php" name="contact_form">
<div class="wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".5s">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="controls">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="controls">
<input type="email" class="form-control email" placeholder="eMail" name="email">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="controls">
<input type="text" class="form-control requiredField" placeholder="Subject" name="subject">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">

<div class="controls">
<textarea rows="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a message here" name="message"></textarea>
</div>

<button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-common">SEND</button>

</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Css and javascript are the default one as bootstrap.
The email domain is info@mywebsite.com, so no gmail or something else.

My action.php (not working) is the one i've found here: http://bootstrapious.com/p/how-to-build-a-working-bootstrap-contact-form

Comment: do you have an smtp server (to process you emails)? do you have an apache server (to process your php pages)?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php ?

Comment: Yes. It's a standard linux hosting server with php, mysql and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't run PHP scripts on your server, it obviously won't work. You need a website host that supports PHP.

Comment: PHP is 100% supported. There is a test button for mail and from there, it works

Comment: Could you provide your version of the PHP script or at least errors from it? Does your hoster provide PHP with `mail()`? (look up in the `phpinfo()`)

Comment: PHP version is 5.5.36. I can see a test function, mail()

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a third party e-mail service I have always found it best to use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) which provides you with full tools to connect to pretty much any SMTP server (including Google mail).

There are plenty of examples available [Here](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examples) to get you up and running.

If, as other users have said, your web server does not have PHP enabled then obviously this isn't going to work - consider providing a bit more information on what exactly isn't working with your example script.

Comment: No error, probably because i've made something wrong. I thought that calling an action in html with a php file as many example with correct naming would work

Comment: You need your SMTP to be configured in php.ini for mail() to work, I've often found PHPMailer is less hassle.

Comment: There should be no problem submitting to a php script from a form in a html file.